# Split ArrayList on blocks

Tags: java, design-patterns, arraylist, split, matcher

I have ArrayList, that looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/16cy5rnk)

I need to extract data based on a string which I type. For example if I type `systém`, I should get this output:

```
001 (07.01.01) programovací systém (m)
systém (m) programovaniaCHCTeMa (f) riporpaMMupoBaiiHM
programming system; programming support environmentsystème (m) de programmationProgrammiersystem (n)
nezbytné programové vybavení potrebné pro používání jed-noho nebo vice programovacích jazyku
```

If I type `komentár`, I should get:

```
004 (07.01.08) komentár (m); poznámka (í)
komentár (m); poznámka (f)
KOMMeHTapHH (m)
comment; remark; note; (computer program) annotationcommentaire (m)
Kommentar (m)
popis*, odkaz n. vysvetlení pripojené k príkazúmve zdrojo-vémprogramu (které se neprojevuje v cílovém programu)
```

But I don't know how to fix it. I've tried to recognize block through first numbers but my output was only line with this number. Here is my code:

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+.*");
  Matcher m;

  String str = "systém";

  for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    String line = al.get(i).toString();
    m = pattern.matcher(line);

    if(m.matches() && line.contains(str))
      System.out.println(line);
      //...Whats next?

  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the algorithm a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: From this ArrayList I need to get block of text. It was lexicon about some computer stuffs. I contains main expression(systém or komentár), languages and explanation of expression. I need algorithm which recognize this blocks. First block start with 001. Second block start with 002. But I have to keep formating of text. If I type systém (input handler is not implemented yet) it must recognize first block 001 and write this 4 lines above. With input komentár it must recognize 004 block, and print output with 6 lines.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your regex is wrong. Try

```
String str = "systém";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(str);
Matcher m;


for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    String line = al.get(i).toString();
    m = pattern.matcher(line);

    if(m.matches() && line.contains(str))
        System.out.println(line);
    //...Whats next?
}
```